# Error en AjaxOption() ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc-5

soy novato y esto practicando el uso de AJAX en ASP.NET MVC.

Tengo una vista parcial en la cual quiero tener un formulario con Ajax.BeginForm() en el que pueda ingresar un numero y por medio de Ajax, al presionarlo me realice una multiplicacion x2 y el resultado lo muestre en un span.

```html
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Contact";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/Lockout.cshtml";
}

<h2>@ViewBag.Title.</h2>
<h3>@ViewBag.Message</h3>

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("DuplicarCantidad_Ajax", "Home",
        new AjaxOption()
        {
            HttpMethod = "POST",
            InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
            UpdateTargetId = "resultado-ajax"
        }))
    {
        <span>Cantidad a duplicar:</span><input type="number" name="cantidadCS" />
        <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Calcular" name="btn-cantidad-ajax" />
        <div>Resultado: <span id="resultado-ajax"></span></div>
    }
)
```

Me esta marcando un error de AjaxOption(). Me indica que falta una directiva using o una referencia de ensamblado.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ya probe usando el using System.Web.Mvc.Ajax, pero aun no se quita el error.

¿Que me puede estar faltando?

Gracias

Comment: Agregaste el paquete Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc?

Comment: Hola has realizado estos dos pasos? Agrega el paquete Nuget desde la consola `Install-Package MicrosoftMvcAjax.Mvc5` y no te olvides de agregar estas referencias a Scripts 
en tu cshtml
`<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>  
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>`

Comment: Si amigo, ya agregue el paquete Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc y referencie los Scripts y aun sigue el error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

el objeto a instanciar se llama `AjaxOptions` no `AjaxOption`

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Contact";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/Lockout.cshtml";
}

<h2>@ViewBag.Title.</h2>
<h3>@ViewBag.Message</h3>

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("DuplicarCantidad_Ajax", "Home",
        new AjaxOptions()
        {
            HttpMethod = "POST",
            InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
            UpdateTargetId = "resultado-ajax"
        }))
    {
        <span>Cantidad a duplicar:</span><input type="number" name="cantidadCS" />
        <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Calcular" name="btn-cantidad-ajax" />
        <div>Resultado: <span id="resultado-ajax"></span></div>
    }
)
```